# history.length doesn't work in chrome or IE 9

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use window.history.length to detect if the user is opening a new tab.  It works in FireFox, but I can't get it to work in IE 9 or in Chrome.  I am really new to Javascript.  Can anyone help me out?  Here is my code:

```
if (window.history.length == 1) {                             
            window.location.href = getBaseURL() + '/Pages/EstimateList.aspx';            
    }
```

Comment: Actually, [as documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length) it should allow you to get count of window.history. Can you add `console.log(window.history)` and share output/error?

Comment: As you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_his_length.asp), window.history.length starts at 0 on IE.

Comment: @TuğcaEker I'm getting 2

Comment: @pie3636 I tried 0 and it doesn't work.

Comment: We would need to see more of your code to understand what is going on. If you are getting 2, it probably means another page was loaded at some point. What do you want to happen in this case? Do you only test the length once? If you want to continously check for a new tab to be opened, then you would probably need to save the current value of `window.history.length` and use a function like `saveInterval` to check periodically.

Comment: window.history won't help you find out if other tabs have been opened, Form the docs:  "For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history."                 You get the value 2 has you have done two history based navigations with the current window. You are being misled that firefox is doing this, it isn't.

Comment: @PeterS I think you answered my question.  I think I need to regroup and rethink the situation.  Thanks.